# Problems in nls application and predictNLS()

Tags: r

I'm trying to compute a model with `nls()` function. With the algorithm "plinear" it works, but since I need to set some constraints on variables I would need to use the "port" algorithm (right?). As I try to put upper and lower limits with "port", it returns me the following error:

```
Error in numericDeriv(form[[3L]], names(ind), env, dir = -1 + 2 * (internalPars <  : 
 Missing value or an infinity produced when evaluating the model
```

The code I'm trying to run is reported below, but I would like to add upper and lower boundaries (a1<0, a2>0, a3>0,a11>0,a12>0,c1<0,c2<0,d<0).

The dataset is composed by 209 rows, I will just write 20 as example:

```
ts_vol <- c(35.02902, 16.85489, 21.18753, 26.64653, 21.37270, 15.75977, 25.92658, 31.27948, 21.99971, 21.96338, 24.04958, 29.05840, 26.38194, 24.55157, 20.99288, 29.52599, 22.80910, 14.38595, 14.10108, 15.68816, 16.28917, 15.25021, 13.71466, 17.86268, 30.42344, 19.64391, 13.38752, 16.13577, 18.95874, 33.33013, 34.48343, 25.46773, 23.30624, 27.19972, 27.24134, 21.30106, 24.43860, 22.25033, 19.15959, 16.16613, 18.58160, 56.75660, 57.54290, 37.29697, 30.42072, 28.11459, 23.10621, 26.99107, 28.27535, 19.92027, 27.89197, 36.00865, 29.45717, 19.85876, 21.46086, 19.73477, 20.12037, 13.42354, 19.46179, 30.02019, 20.15757, 14.09998)

seasonality <- c(14.2987759, 10.0067444, 10.0917355, 7.1605438, 5.8448637, 2.1822238, 10.5109586, 15.7399400, 7.0744498, 4.6085259, 4.8431100, 14.4845057, 15.2721430, 9.5900323, 4.7179485, 8.4621981, 8.5730262, 1.5801878, 3.4490849, 13.0869052, 8.0148475, 0.0000000, 6.7943403, 7.7024009, 6.6107283, 7.5006871, 4.8158292, 3.3694598, 4.1956632, 21.0287532, 21.8981384, 7.1553645, 6.1803712, 16.8434083, 13.6849549, 3.6775580, 2.8474852, 3.0935764, 0.6250771, 4.5489154, 13.7101534, 32.6246540, 23.4174234, 25.0639712, 22.1857079, 14.5643479, 6.2588346, 15.7711578, 12.2818474, 7.6342791, 9.0207043, 16.7666681, 14.2987759, 10.0067444, 10.0917355, 7.1605438, 5.8448637, 2.1822238, 10.5109586, 15.7399400, 7.0744498, 4.6085259)

Price.per.SU <- c(16.48957, 19.34999, 18.25962, 18.39810, 20.45722, 21.76400, 20.21372, 19.60303, 19.99712, 19.28073, 19.69593, 18.91978, 18.98504, 19.54387, 20.06362, 17.00378, 18.90960, 21.05337, 19.95430, 20.35159, 20.15571, 19.58439, 19.65370, 19.71513, 18.86286, 19.58562, 21.59418, 20.06083, 19.83574, 17.80874, 17.80911, 18.34967, 18.61359, 18.78295, 18.77335, 19.01241, 20.02210, 20.71299, 21.24893, 22.18999, 21.14513, 16.69221, 16.61045, 18.66791, 18.60722, 18.83112, 19.41724, 19.19930, 18.95869, 20.64186, 18.72499, 16.76948, 17.22072, 20.90052, 19.64480, 19.32330, 21.03169, 22.53111, 21.72300, 20.33991, 20.62410, 22.16169)

avg.skus <- c(8.61, 8.27, 8.22, 8.72, 8.82, 8.66, 9.11, 9.12, 9.01, 8.80, 8.80, 9.17, 8.74, 8.96, 8.67, 8.70, 8.97, 9.00, 8.48, 8.66, 8.63, 8.56, 8.35, 8.87, 9.16, 8.93, 8.60, 8.54, 8.59, 9.28, 9.24, 9.16, 8.62, 8.99, 9.06, 8.93, 10.61, 10.98, 9.90, 10.17, 10.05, 10.71, 10.35, 10.22, 9.69, 10.05, 9.75, 11.16, 10.85, 10.56, 10.00, 9.67, 9.27, 9.54, 9.67, 9.31, 10.06, 9.10, 9.69, 9.73, 9.45, 8.93)

Promo.Intensity <- c(80.42626, 60.08262, 68.05310, 73.08734, 62.72352, 51.89587, 70.14840, 74.14081, 64.20494, 59.50906, 63.45279, 75.78180, 74.94987, 75.52723, 70.01393, 78.20788, 63.36541, 51.91086, 53.40960, 64.74526, 63.90141, 62.10249, 56.65215, 69.86684, 73.90992, 61.72656, 36.79277, 54.53480, 63.71869, 82.71339, 80.75986, 75.15648, 66.88758, 73.90488, 71.60283, 67.08741, 68.36500, 62.91844, 53.60412, 45.17463, 53.31075, 85.4756586.79556, 79.10584, 74.43157, 69.13770, 62.11144, 69.26417, 66.24158, 57.75128, 67.20956, 79.27606, 75.90128, 68.47024, 72.67202, 70.94737, 64.12909, 52.12396, 64.24846, 76.53143, 64.20466, 48.76596) 

tv_grp <- c(194.982, 177.107, 0.000, 133.872, 155.414, 142.074, 0.000, 142.307, 151.806, 145.152, 0.000, 153.650, 116.267, 124.711, 0.000, 159.048, 161.072, 177.550, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 190.791, 184.932, 180.524, 154.701, 0.000, 0.000, 122.179, 128.961, 124.405, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 223.054, 199.896, 191.496, 224.598, 169.940, 179.732, 185.128, 178.185, 176.900, 0.000, 145.500, 153.600, 185.000, 0.000, 0.000, 123.600, 118.600, 150.700, 195.000, 0.000, 167.500) 

tot_imps <- c(120318011.8, 19745959.8, 11080321.4, 11241050.4, 10436814.4, 11713719.4, 10007182.6, 861767.7, 851138.4, 877360.4, 878836.4, 887613.8, 853696.0, 853653.0, 853459.0, 1078031.4, 1068454.6, 30470946.6, 12084853.7, 5448716.9, 4973420.5, 2975708.5, 192621.5, 1061750.2, 9041992.2, 12633914.2, 11233671.2, 15239968.0, 13650712.0, 16250086.2, 11348654.2, 6883952.2, 5278380.2, 4164298.0, 3653652.0, 1654469.0, 5385038.0, 2395976.0, 166996.0, 3446001.0, 3490578.0, 4811376.0, 5583801.2, 11240835.2, 14926406.2, 15955851.2, 5917931.2, 3640793.8, 8884709.8, 8285379.8, 6850133.0, 9682433.0, 14996405.0, 14955383.0, 8078608.0, 12353827.0, 14069786.0, 17072433.0, 9316567.0, 12822260.0, 9840519.0, 9683338.0)

comp1 <- c(51.24542, 73.39153, 81.90907, 66.67516, 43.92046, 50.90508, 60.52869, 67.63057, 84.57277, 83.07865, 58.57623, 67.67010, 67.94302, 66.94024, 66.44633, 80.66967, 70.31904, 76.65036, 74.82492, 65.52225, 53.86180, 61.79446, 62.07493, 54.71113, 38.19645, 45.28478, 55.12096, 82.28134, 80.00077, 67.73829, 60.22297, 60.75807, 71.64327, 77.29377, 74.24589, 64.65588, 66.23246, 71.37750, 75.01456, 75.66294, 66.68071, 48.87145, 47.13747, 50.66897, 70.71701, 74.31146, 71.14788, 79.67940, 78.11601, 76.51453, 63.69771, 54.23956, 62.78766, 58.96457, 79.47735, 77.08305, 62.69016, 49.30398, 59.21127, 67.32495, 84.03935, 83.58643)

comp2 <- c(58.123150, 55.127803, 23.924385, 7.944631, 4.998671, 12.526376, 14.636604, 37.358866, 44.042235, 37.123075, 18.289929, 8.894145, 5.451644, 10.423766, 11.352387, 9.427235, 7.672527, 10.899753, 4.685643, 4.848270, 28.964286, 33.737687, 34.979779, 9.767463, 6.829782, 4.909928, 4.628397, 3.300629, 2.559040, 4.986786, 6.178137, 9.985976, 7.395175, 6.946521, 3.903940, 3.014870, 4.563825, 17.969185, 16.927008, 5.985154, 6.573522, 11.168568, 8.212214, 8.239787, 10.489083, 20.024802, 23.065666, 33.789254, 30.716135, 31.088065, 5.961156, 5.374192, 3.207137, 7.278813, 7.297533, 3.479118, 6.012788, 4.249513, 8.699291, 16.369601, 19.541992, 15.596893)

covid <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)


st <- list(b=1, a1=1,a2=1,a3=1,a0=1,a11=1,a12=1,c1=1,c2=1,d=1)
x <- nls(ts_vol ~ 
           mapply("^", seasonality, b)*
           mapply("^", Price.per.SU, a1)*
           mapply("^", avg.skus, a2)*
           mapply("^", Promo.Intensity, a3)*
           (a0 + 
              mapply("*", tv_grp, a11) + 
              mapply("*", tot_imps, a12) + 
              mapply("*", comp1, c1) + 
              mapply("*", comp2, c2) + 
              mapply("*", covid, d)), 
         start = st,
         data=data2
         )

summary(x)
```

Also I would like to find the confidence and prediction intervals, is it right to use the `predictNLS()` function (alpha=0.05)?

Comment: We will probably need the whole data set in order to reproduce/answer this ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would use `nlsLM(...)` from the `minpack.lm` package, not `nls(...)`. The Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm is much more robust in my experience, plus it has provision for lower and upper bounds.

Second, I do not see why you need to use `mapply(...)` for your formula (although I may be misunderstanding what you are trying to achieve).

Here is an example based on the data you provided.

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
library(minpack.lm)
##
#
df  <- data.table(ts_vol, seasonality, Price.per.SU, avg.skus, Promo.Intensity, tv_grp, tot_imps, comp1, comp2, covid)
fit <- nlsLM(ts_vol ~ seasonality^b * Price.per.SU^a1 * avg.skus^a2 * Promo.Intensity^a3 * (a0 + tv_grp^a11 + tot_imps^a12 + comp1^c1 + comp2^c2 +covid^d), 
             data=df, start=st,
             lower = c(b= -Inf, ao=-Inf, a1= -Inf, a2=0,    a3=0,    a11=0,    a12=0,    c1= -Inf, c2= -Inf, d=-Inf), 
             upper = c(b=  Inf, a0= Inf, a1=0,     a2= Inf, a3= Inf, a11= Inf, a12= Inf, c1=0,     c2=0,     d=0),
             control = list(maxiter=1000))
summary(fit)
## 
## Formula: ts_vol ~ seasonality^b * Price.per.SU^a1 * avg.skus^a2 * Promo.Intensity^a3 * 
##         (a0 + tv_grp^a11 + tot_imps^a12 + comp1^c1 + comp2^c2 + covid^d)
##
## Parameters:
##       Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
## b    7.221e-02  7.399e-02   0.976 0.333583    
## a1  -3.808e+00  6.765e-01  -5.629 7.38e-07 ***
## a2   0.000e+00  5.399e-01   0.000 1.000000    
## a3   0.000e+00  4.203e-01   0.000 1.000000    
## a0   1.464e+06  5.140e+06   0.285 0.776841    
## a11  2.307e+00  6.680e-01   3.454 0.001108 ** 
## a12  6.401e-01  1.806e-01   3.544 0.000842 ***
## c1   0.000e+00  2.797e+05   0.000 1.000000    
## c2   0.000e+00  7.567e+04   0.000 1.000000    
## d    0.000e+00  2.285e-03   0.000 1.000000   
##...

df[, pred:=predict(fit)]
df[, resid:=residuals(fit)]
df[, std.resid:=residuals(fit)/summary(fit)$sigma]
##
ggplot(df, aes(x=ts_vol, y=pred))+
  geom_point(shape=21)+
  geom_abline(color='dodgerblue', linetype='dashed')
```

[image]

```
ggplot(df, aes(sample=std.resid))+
  stat_qq(geom='point', shape=21)+
  stat_qq_line()+
  labs(title='Normal Q-Q Plot')
```

[image]